# ¿Porque no genera QR?

Tags: php, qrcode

tengo una duda, al generar QR con php con **qrlib.php**, de manera local si me genera los QR y me actualiza la imagen, pero cuando lo subo a mi servidor, no me genera la imagen, ya revise la libreria y no veo diferencia entre uno y otro.

Les presento mi código:

```
 <?php
include "../phpqrcode/qrlib.php";
$codigo=$_GET['cadena'];

QRcode::png($codigo,"../images/qr/codigoqr.png","QR_ECLEVEL_H",10,2);
$imagen='../images/qr/codigoqr.png';

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($imagen));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($imagen));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($imagen);
?>
```

Será por que mi servidor es ubuntu y mi local windows.

Gracias

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so] aprovecha un momento para hacer el [tour] y consulta [ask] para mejorar tu pregunta. ¿Ya revisaste que la url sea válida ? Usualmente ese **../** que apunta correctamente en localhost sobra en el servidor. Si es correcto ¿ revisaste el tema de permisos ? si no los tienes los paths van a fallar.

Answer (score 1):

La solución esta en colocarlo en una carpeta absoluta, por motivos de seguridad no deja guardar la imagen en el servidor.

Les comparto la solución por si alguien lo necesita.

```
 <?php
include "../phpqrcode/qrlib.php";
$codigo=$_GET['cadena'];

QRcode::png($codigo,"/tmp/codigoqr.png","QR_ECLEVEL_H",10,2);
$imagen='/tmp/codigoqr.png';

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($imagen));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($imagen));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($imagen);
?>
```